# extract text from html string with Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

Here is the html string in question.

```html
<div class="def ddef_d db">a <a class="query" href="https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/book" title="book">book</a> of grammar <a class="query" href="https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rule" title="rules">rules</a>: </div>
```

With BeautifulSoup, this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltxt, 'lxml')
soup.text
```

gets me

> a book of grammar rules:

which is exactly what I want.

With scrapy, how do I get the same result?

```
from scrapy import Selector
sel = Selector(text=htmltxt)
sel.css('.ddef_d::text').getall()
```

this code gets me

> ['a ', ' of grammar ', ': ']

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aYou can use this code to get all text inside div and its child:

```
text = ''.join(sel.css('.ddef_d ::text').getall())
print(text)
```

your selector returns text only from the div, but part of text located inside child elements (a), that's why you have to add space before `::text` to include child text into result.